# cancel last chmod?

Tags: sudo, chmod, undo, hfs+

Today is a great day for me - anyone can suggest other restore method than from tape with regard to my last glorious command

```
sudo chmod -R o=rw /
```

Btw I am on HFS+

Comment: Restore from *tape*?

Comment: No, but at least do `chmod -R o=r /` first.

Comment: one more detail.. /bin has ben modified so I can't run anything anymore. no sudo, no nothing, actually, system would not boot anymore :)

Comment: Have you tried using a bootable linux distro to set all the bin dir contents to executable? The main bin dirs are in the `PATH` variable which (on debian at least) is in /etc/profile